# How can I run the IntelliJ debugger on unit tests in a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, junit, intellij-idea

I'm working with a multi-artifact Maven project where artifacts in the project have a few dependencies on each other.  I am using IntelliJ 9.  I'd like to be able to set breakpoints in my unit tests, but when I right-click on the unit tests folder for my artifact and choose "Debug 'All Tests'", I get a Class not found exception referring to a class in a separate Maven artifact.

I can run the Maven "test" goal on the parent artifact and it works fine.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to run the unit tests for a specific package.

I was able to get this to work by making a new JUnit run/debug configuration in IntelliJ.  I told it to run the tests in the specific package and for "Use classpath and JDK of module", I picked the root Maven artifact.

Answer (score 16):

In you run Maven from command line, you will be able to run it with debugger enabled and just attach Idea as remote debugger. That's how I usually use it.

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" test
```

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html

This will allow debugger connection to port 8000 and wait for you to attach before execution.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I was able to make it work by tweaking a JUnit run/debug configuration in IntelliJ.

Comment: I am thinking that this would not be very efficient for me since I only want to run the unit tests for a specific package... I'd have to run mvn test on the root POM which would run all unit tests

Comment: You could always use -Dtest as described here. But if you solved it in Idea - great!

Comment: I missed the link to surefire single test page. Here it is http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the maven command: -DforkCount=0
i.e clean verify -DforkCount=0